# Comparing timestamp values in one database

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I'm using SQL Server or Azure SQL databases (depending on environment).

Inside database I have some tables using datatype `timestamp` for versioning and some of them not using it.

For example: tables `A` and `B` have column `timestamp ver` and tables `C` and `D` doesn't have such column.

I'm using Entity Framework. Can I somehow safely convert this value (matched to `byte[]`) to `uint64`? Is it guaranteed that after converting the higher value is the later row was modified: if I take row `a` from table `A` and row `b` from table `B` `a.convertedVer > b.convertedVer` if and only if `a` was modified later than `b`?

I need to handle requests: "give me all rows from `A` matching sth and having `ver` higher than `myVer`".

Comment: What's wrong with `byte[]`? You don't have to check if the value is higher, just if it is equal. In any case, yes, the timestamp will always be a 8-byte value, so `UInt64` should be ok.

Comment: I updated question. I need to handle requests: give me all rows from A matching sth and having ver higher than myVer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Gert Arnold answer it is guaranteed that the higher value is the later row was modified.

Creating code converting `byte[8]` to `uint64` is not hard. We can use `BitConverter` or we can simply add bytes shifted by 0, 8, 16, 24, 32, ....

The one last problem: how to create query `Where RowVersion > someUInt64` in `Entity Framework`.

Few facts:

1. MS SQL understands `Where RowVersion > someUInt64` and `Where RowVersion > someBytes`.
2. Azure SQL understands `Where RowVersion > someUInt64` and `Where RowVersion > someBytes`.
3. C# can't compare `byte[]` and `byte[]` nor `byte[]` and `uint64`.

So even if database are able to process these requests, we can't create such requests in `C# Entity Framework`.

We need `C#` to understand comparing `byte[]` and `byte[]` or `byte[]` and `uint64`. First case is easier. What we can easily do is creating method comparing `byte[]` and `byte[]`.

```
public static int Compare(this byte[] b1, byte[] b2)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

We don't need to implement it. `T-SQL` has it implemented already. All we need to do is to make `C#` compile our code in which we are using `Compare` method.

Now we can convert our query to: `Where(v => v.Compare(someBytes) > 0)`.

Comment: Nice! I added some background to my own answer. You can mark your answer as accepted to guide future readers to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it guaranteed that after converting the higher value is the later row was modified?

Yes, from [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx):

> The rowversion data type is just an *incrementing* number (...) Each database has a counter that is *incremented* for each insert or update operation that is performed on a table that contains a rowversion column within the database.

(my emphasis)

By the way, note that `timestamp` is deprecated. Currently, it's just a synonym of `rowversion`.

> Can I somehow safely convert this value (matched to byte[]) to uint64?

Yes, but the word *somehow* is nasty. Very nasty.

In T-SQL you can write a query like

```sql
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE rowversion > @someRowversion
```

As you know, Entity Framework returns `rowversion` as `byte[8]`. A byte array is not comparable (without custom comparers). So we can't write:

```cs
db.MyTable.Where(t => t.RowVersion > someByteArray);
```

It doesn't compile. If only EF could bypass the C# compiler and translate the expression into SQL nonetheless! (Of course it never will).

Now what?

Let's say you've got a converter that converts the `byte[]` into a `UInt64`. (This converter could use a `BitConverter`, but there are some endianness details I don't go into now). You can't write

```cs
db.MyTable.Where(t => MyConverter.Convert(t.RowVersion) > someUInt64);
```

EF will object that it can't translate `MyConverter.Convert(t.RowVersion)` into SQL. And

```cs
db.MyTable.AsEnumerable()
          .Where(t => MyConverter.Convert(t.RowVersion) > someUInt64);
```

is not an option, because it will pull all `MyTable` into memory.

Maybe I'm missing something very obvious (I hope), but comparing `rowversion` values in EF LINQ queries seems to be a dead end. I think you better resort to stored procedures or views to achieve what you want.

**Edit**

So yes! I was missing something, but not too obvious, fortunately. As Ari has explained, it's possible to create a *method stub* `Compare` that EF picks up while translating an expression into SQL. It's never executed in CLR.

To give some more background: in the EF source it's all in the `LinqExpressionNormalizer`. The method `VisitMethodCall()` looks for a number of method names that, if found in the expression, are converted to expressions and merged with the containing expression. These methods are

- Equals (static): `Object.Equals(x, y)`
- CompareString (VB): `x = y`
- Compare (static): `Class.Compare(x, y)`
- Equals (instance): `x.Equals(y)`
- CompareTo (instance): `x.CompareTo(y)`
- Contains (instance): `List<T> x.Contains(y)`

Comment: I found out that if I define `Compare` method for `byte[]` doing anything (for example throwing `NotImplementedException`) I can write `.Where(t => t.RowVersion.Compare(myVer) > 0)`. This is very ugly, but works as expected. I think that MS should implement `rowversion` as `uint64`.

Comment: Well, that's cool! Would you mind giving a brief explanation of this approach as an answer to your own question?